# MVC5 bundles not registering the proper AJAX files

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax, bundle

The scripts that are needed for an Ajax.ActionLink call are not properly registering on my production server.  The Ajax.Action link works on my development environment. I am not seeing a jquery.unobtrusive file listed in the Scripts but I do see a jquery.validate.unobtrusive.  I tried adding this to the bundle instead but still no luck.  Can someone help me get these bundles setup correctly.  I have listed the files that are in my scripts folder below.
BundleConfig.cs:

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                      "~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js"
                      ));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                             "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                             "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css",
                             "~/Content/site.css"
                             ));
    }
```

In my _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
```

Here are the files that I have listed in the scripts directory:
[image: Script files in project]

Here is a screenshot of the missing files when loading the page:
[image: HTML Source:]

[image: Debugging result:]

Here is my Ajax.ActionLink call in case it is needed:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("+Add another activity type", "CreateNewType", new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "divTypes",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                        HttpMethod = "POST"
                    })
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I went back through though the file structure and found the jquery.unobtrusive.ajax file in the project and copied that to the working directory on the development server and it came to life.

I then deleted it and added this to the scripts folder by right clicking and choosing add existing item.  Once I re-published this worked as well, and is a better solution in case it needs to be redeployed later.